# How to get a link from a jquery mobile web app open iphone's native map application

Tags: iphone, maps

I have a link in a jquery mobile web app that links to address. I've tried using apple's map url scheme but have had not luck in getting the link to open in the iPhone's map application.

Currently, I have tried the following:

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=dallas">Map: 2001 Flora Street, Dallas</a>
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=2001+Flora+Street,+Dallas,+TX">Map: 2001 Flora Street, Dallas</a>
```

Both links fail to open the iphone map application, and instead open the location in a google maps web app window.

Any way to make the address open in the iphone native maps app?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like changing the code to the following works:

```
<a href="maps:q=2001+Flora+Street,+Dallas,+TX">Map: 2001 Flora Street, Dallas</a>
```

Comment: Take a look at this article about [Opening native map apps](http://habaneroconsulting.com/en/insights/Opening-native-map-apps-from-the-mobile-browser.aspx#.UhX_BJK1FSI)

Comment: New link [Opening native map apps](http://habaneroconsulting.com/blog/posts/Opening_native_map_apps_from_the_mobile_browser.aspx#.U3I-v61dXkM)